# Требуется ли двоеточие и кавычки внутри предложения, если это диалог?

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

- А пока едем, ответь на вопрос: "Что ты подразумеваешь под словом Вселенная?"

Answer (score 4):

Если доверять [примерам из Нацкорпуса](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%F2%E2%E5%F2%FC%20%ED%E0%20%E2%EE%EF%F0%EE%F1), двоеточие нужно, а кавычки обычно не ставятся. При этом сам вопрос начинается со строчной буквы.

> *А пока едем, ответь на вопрос: что ты подразумеваешь под словом Вселенная?*

(То, что это диалог, не играет большой роли, потому что один из собеседников просит другого ответить на вопрос и формулирует его, в другой ситуации не было бы причин для других знаков. А вообще, другую-то и сложно представить: если есть слово *ответь,* значит, кто-то к кому-то обращается и, выходит, это и есть диалог.)

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с Артемом, **он предлагает правильный вариант оформления** (БСП, а не прямая речь).

Прямая речь в диалоге возможна, но она должна быть обращена к третьему лицу, например:

— А что было потом?

— А потом он у меня спросил: "Что ты подразумеваешь под словом Вселенная?"

Comment: если честно, я не совсем разобралась. Вот идёт диалог.  - Арина, а пока мы едем, ответь на вопрос: " Что ты подразумеваешь под словом Всленная?" И далее снизу ставим тире и оформляем слова уже Ани. В таком варианте всё правильно?

Comment: Правильно будет так, как сказал Артем: - Арина, а пока мы едем, ответь на  вопрос: что ты подразумеваешь под словом Вселенная?